# Open normal subgroups with finite image under extensions

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, complete-spaces, semidirect-product

Let $A$ be a (discrete) countable group such that for ever completely metrizable group $M$ and any (not necessarily continuous) homomorphism $f\colon M \to A$ there exists some open normal subgroup $N\trianglelefteq M$ with finite image $f(N)$.

Now, let $G$ be an extension of $A$ by a finite (discrete) group. Does $G$ admit the same property above?

By the universal embedding theorem of Krasner–Kaloujnine it is enough to show that this holds for semidirect products of $A\rtimes F$, where $F$ is a finite group. Further, we might assume that for a homomorphism $g\colon M \to A\rtimes F$ every identity neighbourhood in $M$ maps surjectively onto $A\rtimes F$ (by replacing $M$ with some open normal subgroups with minimal image with respect to $M\to A\rtimes F \to F$). If (after those reductions) $F$ is trivial, we are done. But in the other case, I am completely stuck.

Comment: I have hard time understanding this property. Especially since completely metrizable group is either discrete or uncountable, but $A$ is countable? Can you give me an example of such group? Or give a reference where it is thoroughly discussed?

Comment: For example the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ (or any free (abelian) group) by a result of Dudly. Then you can construct new examples by taking finite direct products with finite groups. Basically, is this stable under construction of extensions?

Comment: Those examples are with discrete topology? This sounds trivial considering that $\ker f$ is open normal in such situation. Meaning this will hold for any group $M$, regardless of whether it is completely metrizable or not. Unless you don't assume that $M\to A$ homomorphism is continuous?

Comment: I don't assume the homomorphism to be continuous, going to clarify this in the question.

Comment: I see. What a weird property. Well, thanks for clarification.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4820140/742)